# Is there a way to color a background image with css? As in, just the image

Tags: javascript, css, colors

So I have a `<div>`, and inside the `<div>` an icon as a `background-image`, 15px in size, white, with a transparent background. Is there any way to override the white color of the icon without coloring in the div which contains it, using JavaScript and CSS?

I've read a few solutions on SO and CSS Tricks, such as a tint overlay (obviously not a solution to my problem because I just want the icon colored in, not the background), and some suggestions that were baffling and wrong (using `background-image` in conjunction with `background-color`).

This seems trivial to me. Or are we not there with CSS3 yet?

Comment: CSS is not really a tool for direct modifying of images. `<canvas>` in HTML5 is more likely a candidate for a solution.

Comment: Gahhh that's going to make this a bit complicated. I'm familiar with canvas. But would probably require a lot of messy code to attempt what I'm doing. There really is no way with CSS and/or JavaScript?

Comment: I would edit your image, turn it into a .png with transparent whitespace.

Comment: Out of curiosity why not use a container?

Comment: Nay. I wanted to keep it very simple, but to give more context:  I have a search box, and the containing divs I'm talking about are results based on objects. Icons are produced based on property values, and I want to color those icons based on a "score" property value. 

So editing one image will not fix this. 

So editing one image will not fix this.

Comment: @Drew R, tried putting the icon in its own div and giving that a background-image and background-color value but then the background is colored in as well as the icon. Same problem.

Comment: @Gaweyne apologies I misread your question :) Makes sense now.
You want to dynamically color an icon instead of using multiple different colored images. Could you turn your image into a SVG or maybe a font?

Comment: @Drew R that might be worth researching. Can you do that with any old tiny png image? :o

Comment: I'm not sure - I think Glyphicons are served as webfonts, SVG would probably be more elegant. Sorry I can't be more definite!

Comment: That's OK. Thanks. I'll google some. I did see someone suggest that elsewhere on SO but I didn't think it was possible. Maybe I can convert them with gimp somehow. Developing on Ubuntu.

Comment: if you want a webkit only solution for now, you can use [CSS Masking](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/pne6dmj3/)

Comment: O! If only that worked with mozilla and safari as well. That would be the solution. Don't have to worry about IE at all for my project.

Comment: works with safari as well, but for firefox you will have to use [SVG](http://robert.ocallahan.org/2008/06/applying-svg-effects-to-html-content_04.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of approaches you can take to this:

1. Convert your icon to an embedded SVG, allowing you to use the CSS `fill` property.
2. Add your icon to a web font, allowing you to use the CSS `font-color` property.

The second approach would be my preferred one and involves converting the image to an SVG first anyway, so I'll provide an overview of that. You are limited to monochrome icons, though usually this isn't a problem for icons.

## Step 1: trace SVG from bitmap

Both these steps start with you converting the bitmap image to a vector image. Here are some resources for that if you don't want to recreate it by hand:

- [Image tracing tutorial for Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/tracing/tutorial-tracing.html).
- [Image tracing tutorial for Adobe Illustrator](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/image-trace.html).
- [Free online image tracing tool](http://www.autotracer.org/). (I haven't tested this!)

## Step 2: create icon font

Again, there are many options for creating fonts from SVGs—free online tools like [IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io), [Inkscape's Font Editor](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/01/how-to-make-your-own-icon-webfont/), [grunt-webfont](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-webfont)… Find a tool that suits you.

I recommend IcoMoon: it automatically creates all the necessary and generates a stylesheet for you, so you can skip step 3!

## Step 3: generate web font assets

To use your new font on the web, you need to provide it in several different formats for compatibility and let browsers know about them using [a `@font-face` at-rule](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/). Tools like [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) or [Fontie](https://fontie.flowyapps.com/home) will do both of these for you—and some, such as IcoMoon, combine this with the previous step.

## That's it!

Now, you can render the image as a pseudo-element with the icon glyph as `content`, and change your icon colour by changing the `font-color` in your CSS.

Comment: I've ended up doing something slightly different but this is by far the most straightforward solution. I've done this before on a very old project and it worked. It didn't come to mind working on this because I have to develop on an offline machine at work.

Comment: @Gaweyne Wait—you mean the machine you're developing *for* (understandable) or the machine you're developing *with*? I really hope the former! :)

Comment: @Gaweyne Also, out of interest, what did you end up doing?

Comment: Sorry for delay. Found out that someone else working on the app had it covered. They had produced these images in gimp that had a transparent background and an opaque shape of the icon cut into the center. So when you changed the background color of the image with css, the icon would be whatever color you wanted it to be. Not really a code based solution, so much as a graphic design one.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with css filters.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter

**Edit:**

Made an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/j0k7sr9x/1

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="background">

    </div>
</div>

#background{
    background-image: url("http://s24.postimg.org/es9caxnbl/Untitled_1.png");
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    filter: invert(60%) sepia(100%) hue-rotate(-45deg) saturate(500%);
}
```

However you have to play around with the values, you can add saturation, etc to it.

**EDIT2:**

Also it is supported by most browsers. See: http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20filter

Comment: Experimental too. Probably baaad idea for my project. :o

Comment: whether or not it is achievable with filters, you should post an example in your answer. sticking an external link with not explanation will render the answer useless should the linked page go down one day.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith yes you can

Comment: @godzsa you just did the exact opposite of what op asked for. he needs the icon colored, not its transparent background mate

Comment: @Banana I did what he asked, the red background is the container div, just so you can see the picture's background stays transparent, the icon is colored blue

Comment: @godzsa you will get my upvote if you can make the circle itself red, without the backgrounds of the container and image

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith OP said the icon had transparent background, that is not possible with .jpg so OP must use .gif or .png, my solution will work with both

Comment: Very good solution but 1) the values filter takes, as opposed to simple hex rgba colors, poses problems for my specific project and 2) the experimental nature of the solution, according to the mozilla docs. Can't risk using this. :o